# Windows 7 task scheduler keeps returning operational code 2

Tags: windows-7, scheduled-tasks

I set up a scheduled task to run under my account.  Everything it runs, even if it is successful, returns an operational code of (2).  I looked this up this error code at the below link, and it claims it cannot find the specific file.

http://www.hiteksoftware.com/knowledge/articles/049.htm

Even if I do something *very* simple, I get back operational code of (2).  For example:

```
run program: cmd.exe

start in path: c:\windows\system32
```

I start the task and I see the process running in my task manager, so I kill the task.  I then check in the history of scheduled task and it shows up as (2).

Something more realistic of what I am doing:

```
<?
/* file in c:\php\test.php */
echo "hello";
?>
```

run program: `php.exe`

start in path: `c:\php`

arguments: `-f test.php`

Everything works in the command line, but Windows schedule task keeps returning operational code (2).  I should be seeing an operational code of (0), which means successful, correct?

Comment: As far as I can see "Opcode" is not the same as "Last Run Result". I have a task end with result 1 and the "Operational Code" in the history is 2. However it seems Opcode 2 means "FAILED": https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc727082(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You may not have put a path in the "Start In (Optional) box of the Edit Action dialog box.

Even though you had a path on the program that was being executed, Windows 7 still wants you to tell it where to run the program.

Comment: I have the full path of the program in the "Start in (optional)" field.  In fact, without it, my script won't even run!

Comment: This did not really solve it for me, but it seems to be a popular solution.  I believe my issue is with how php.exe exits its scripts and the return code it sends to Windows.  I just ended up ignoring the Windows return code 2.

Comment: Odd that it says "optional" on the field... but filling it in fixed it for me. Thank you!

Comment: It is not odd that it says optional. You don't have to put it in, but if you don't, your script or executable cannot depend on the current directory being set to what you might expect.

Comment: another thing i've discovered, in addition to needing to supply the "Start in" path, is to NOT use quotes in that field!  even if the directory in which you want to start contains spaces, quotes are not needed nor allowed.  just another gotcha with the scheduler.

Answer (score 7):

**TL/DR:** Don't worry about it. This just means the task finished, but tells you nothing about whether it was successful or how it failed. Look at the "Last Run Result" for that information.

---

The question and the top answer are confusing the notion of a "return code", which shows up in Task Scheduler as the "Last Run Result" with the "OpCode"/"Operational Code" that shows up in the history of a task.

If I create a simple Python program that does nothing more than `sys.exit(7)`, and run it via task scheduler, I get a Last Run Result of 0x7, and an opcode of 2.  If I have it do nothing, or `sys.exit(0)`, I get a Last Run Result of "The operation completed successfully (0x0)" and still an opcode of 2. In other words, the return code from the executed program determines the Last Run Result. The OpCode appears to be a constant 2. This also establishes that the opcode 2 is not related to the return code 2 that likely means the file's not found. We know the file was found as it executed, and returned different Last Run Results depending on the code contained.

Further, a [Windows forum post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/49340c31-a863-43af-8f1d-bf2e90c52da4/task-scheduler-operational-codes?forum=windbg) points out that this history view is really coming out of the event log. Sure enough, I can find the same events in the event log (always with a value of 2). This means the definition of the OpCode is going to be the same as the definition used for events, and is less of a task scheduler concept than a Windows event concept.

What is an opcode for an event?  I've struggled to get a clear answer, but as best I can tell, it appears it's ultimately controlled by the program writing to the event log. There's [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wes/defining-tasks-and-opcodes) around for defining opcodes in your program. In this case, the thing writing to the event log would be Task Scheduler itself or something else in Windows.

A final observation: If I go to the event viewer and look for `Log: Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational`, `Source: Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler` and `Event ID: 102,201`, add the column for Operational Code, and sort, I see it is *always* a 2. And events 100 and 200 are *always* a 1. This applies not just to my manual experiments, but also includes every other random program that's using scheduled tasks, e.g. Dropbox and Google updaters that are working as far as I know.

Put all this together and I would strongly bet that the events generated while starting up a scheduled task are hardcoded by Windows to use an opcode of 1 when writing to the event log, and the events generated while finishing a task (successful or not - which goes in the Last Run Result) are hardcoded by Windows to use an opcode of 2 when writing to the event log. This opcode appears to be a red herring that doesn't affect anything we need to worry about beyond curiosity.

Comment: This is correct. Operation code ("OpCode") tells nothing about the exit code of the program/script. It's going to be 1 for "Task Started" and "Action Started" events, and will be 2 for "Action Completed" and "Task Completed" events. If you look at the History for the task, then click the "Action Completed" event, you will see in the General tab, that the last thing it mentions is "with return code 0", or whatever your return code was.

Answer (score 3):

I was striking out until I just deleted & re-created the scheduled task...now it works.  Don't know why but there it is.

Comment: Same for me haha, weird

Answer (score 1):

Okay I know I am late to the party here, but I think a lot of the problem stems from confusing the *Operational Code* with a *Return Code*. I'm not an expert in Windows programming or internals (I make a living using a Windows system to program, but my programming isn't for Windows systems).

If I understand correctly:
The *Operational Code* is set by what ever routine being run at whatever value the programmer decided to set it at. 
The *Return Code* is indicative of success or failure.

Consider the following (edited) example from the history of one of my scheduled tasks:
Event 201, Task Category "Action completed" shows an *Operational Code* of (2).
Down below under the General tab, is the message:

Task Scheduler successfully completed task "\My_task" , instance "{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}" , action "C:.....\blahblah.exe" with return code 0.

There's the indication of success. A different return code would indicate a failure. The *Operational Code* of (2) merely indicates that the routine was finished (in this case) when reported. I don't believe there's any set values to be interpreted for the *Operation Code*.

Comment: not helping at all, take a look at the task scheduler in windows and you will understand what he means with operational code 2 - a single task will give back not only one op.-code .. if there is a code 2 you know there is a problem

Comment: I don't agree with roeb.  I have several tasks exiting with OpCode 2, and yet the logs and the results indicate that everything went ok (manually verified). In addition, different steps in the process returned different operational codes ("Action started (1), Task Completed (2))".

Answer (score 1):

I've been having a similar issue and found that in addition to what was suggested in both the accepted answer and its comments I had to do one other thing. I had to re-create the task and set its "configure for" to **Windows Server 2003, Windows XP, or Windows 2000** I dont understand why, since its not for any of those OS' but after I did so my task actually worked.

If this runs, and works, yet you still get an error code try entering `exit 0` at the end of your script.

It took me a lot of googling to find that so hopefully this is helpful to someone.

Answer (score 1):

@**ojchase** is right.
Opcodes are attached to events by the event provider. An opcode defines a numeric value that identifies the activity or a point within an activity that the application was performing when it raised the event.

Opcode 1 means that, when producing the event, the application was in the start of an activity.
Opcode 2 means that, when producing the event, the app. was at the end of an activity.

So opcodes have little to do with success or failure.

Sources:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventing.reader.standardeventopcode?view=net-5.0
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventing.reader.eventopcode?view=net-5.0

Comment: Thank you! I was bothered that I couldn't find the source/meaning of the actual value 2. I feel better seeing some documentation defining it.