# Running a php script using wget and Windows Scheduler

Tags: php, windows, command-line, localhost, wget

On my laptop, I have installed a webserver and have written a script. Accessing the script through `http://localhost/test/search.php` in any browser makes it run properly: it searches for, downloads and stores certain tweets.

I now want to make the script run automagically every 20 minutes, so I downloaded and installed `wget` for Windows in `C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin\wget.exe`. I then created a Windows Task with the following Action (filled in on the Actions tab):

```
Program/script:
"C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin\wget.exe"

Add arguments (optional): -O - -q -t 1 http://localhost/test/search.php
```

As expected, every 20 minutes a command line opens to run the script. However, nothing happens. The script isn't initialized. I am sure all my paths are correct. What could be causing that the script doesn't get executed? The command line disappears in a matter of milliseconds, so I cannot see what it says...

Comment: i dont understand why you need to use wget in first place. You could just execute the file as you would do to run it from CLI. `php -f c:\xampp\htdocs\search.php`

Comment: If I do this, the cli opens but it returns many php errors, ie. `Warning: include_once(includes/template.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\htdocs\test\includes\bootstrap.php on line 12; Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'includes/template.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\XAMPP\php\PEAR') in D:\htdocs\test\includes\bootstrap.php on line 12` which is weird, because when I run the script from the browser I don't get these errors. Why does the scipt, when invoked like this, look for `template.php` in C:\XAMPP\php\PEAR instead of D:\htdocs\test\includes?

Comment: the script is being invoked right. PHP needs to be in the script directory for includes to work. see sumoanand's answer below

Comment: I'm looking at sumoanand's script but I don't understand how to get it to work. To clarify: I have installed XAMPP in `C:\XAMPP\`, so php.exe is located at `C:\XAMPP\php\php.exe`. Howver, `htdocs` is located on a different drive: `D:\htdocs\`. So the php script I'm trying to run is located at `D:\htdocs\test\search.php`. `search.php` includes a bunch of files all located at `D:\htdocs\test\includes`. When you say "php needs to be in the script directory for includes to work", do you mean I can simply copy `php.exe` from `C:\XAMPP\php\php.exe` to 'D:\htdocs\test\php.exe'?

Comment: no not copy.. you need to cd to the script folder. like sumoanand said , just create a batch file `task1.bat` with the given content. and set the path to the batch file in your scheduled task.

Comment: I have created a search.bat with contents `cd d:\htdocs\test [return] php search.php`. However, cli returns `'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file` when I run it. Any thoughts?

Comment: Ok, i got it now.In this case, do this: step1: cd C:\XAMPP\php\   , Step 2: php D:\htdocs\test\search.php . If you get some error now, then it is related to script/framework only & you need to invoke it differently.

Comment: @sumoanand Now I am lost. I have created `D:\htdocs\ting\search.bat` with contents `cd c:\XAMPP\php [return] php d:\htdocs\ting\search.php`. (directory is renamed from _test_ to _ting_). However, I get the following [errors](http://i.imgur.com/NTWi01k.png) even though the files really do [exist](http://i.imgur.com/dUK3fY9.png). I don't think this has anything to do with the framework I use (I wrote it myself and it is very straightforward). Any ideas?

Comment: What happens when you open a command line and simply run `"C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin\wget.exe" -O - -q -t 1 http://localhost/test/search.php` ?

Comment: `C:\Users\Pr0no>"C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin\wget.exe" -O - -q -t 1 http://localhost/ting/search.php
SYSTEM_WGETRC = c:/progra~1/wget/etc/wgetrc
syswgetrc = C:\Program Files\GnuWin32/etc/wgetrc
C:\Users\Pr0no>` I get no errors but the script isn't being executed. This is weird, because when I run `http://localhost/ting/search.php` in a browser, the script _does_ get executed..?! This is the exact same problem as in the OP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mention two path to `search.php` : one is with `/test`, the other is with `/ting`. Make sure you are using the same in the browser and wget.

If you request a page that does not exist, you will get no error if you supply `-q`. Replace it with `-v` or `--verbose` to see what is wrong.

```
c:\gnuwin32\bin\wget.exe -O - --verbose -t 1 http://localhost/test/search.php
--2013-02-25 23:42:03--  http://localhost/test/search.php
Resolving localhost... ::1, 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost|::1|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2013-02-25 23:42:03 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

When you get the command line working, you can focus on running it with the task scheduler.

You can run the task as yourself, or any other accounts. Using `LOCAL SERVICE` allows you to run it without providing a password, even if you are logged out. Just make shure that the account you selected has permission to the directory where wget is located.

[Others have mentionned](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12964998/591064) that you must set the path of your scheduled task, or else you will get the operationnal code (2) you showed in your screen shot. It will also make sure WIndows find `wget.exe` dependencies, namely `libeay32.dll` and `libssl32.dll`.

[image: Set a working directory for your scheduled task].

Finally, simplify. Run php from the command line. [The link above is an example of that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12964998/591064) with a simple script.

Write you code so that you can call search.php standalone from the command line. No need to put an HTTP client and a web server in between. Here are [a bunch of sample scripts](http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/10-code-snippets-to-interact-with-twitter) for various Twitter related operations.

Comment: @ixe13 Thanks for your reply! (1) I renamed directory _test_ to _ting_  after writing the OP (2) When running `"c:\program files\gnuwin32\bin\wget.exe" -O - --verbose -t 1 http://localhost/ting/search.php` all went well except for the HTTP request: `HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Authorization Required`...and then it struck me: I recently protected _ting_ by adding a username/password to the `.htaccess`. My browser obviously remembers the login code, hence runs `search.php` without any problem, but the cmd request to `search.php` got blocked. By deleting `.htaccess` it now works

Comment: However, how can I send the username and password along with the `wget` request in `cmd`? Here's the relevant bit of `.htaccess`: `AuthName "Protected Area" AuthType Basic AuthUserFile d:/.htpasswd require valid-user` with `.htpasswd` contents being: `the_user:the_passwd`

Comment: Oh, got it: `http://the_user:the_passwd@localhost/...` I can only send the reward to you in two hours, so it'll be coming your way then :-)

Answer (score 1):

Please create a bat file, mention all commands there, like the one mentioned by Broncha in the comment & then add it to the Windows task scheduler.

```
task1.bat
-----------
cd c:\xampp\htdocs\test
php search.php
```

Comment: Please see my latest comment above. How do I properly invoke PHP?

Answer (score 1):

You should test your script from command line to know if it is working or not. Simply run this on `cmd` to check

```
"C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin\wget.exe" -O - -q -t 1 http://localhost/test/search.php
```

Task scheduler has lots of tabs for settings, check history tab to see scheduled task history, where you can check the exit code for last several runtimes. Look for events like this in the history :

> Event ID : 201 Task Category : Action Completed

Check its exit code `action "C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\wget.exe" with return code x`. If it is zero then it is working, any other integer means error.

Please tell which windows are you using ? Also post the output of the command mentioned above so that I can know exactly what is the error in Task Scheduler.

Comment: Might not be a (bounty worthy) answer, but essential steps to find the problem !

Comment: In the task history, I see [this](http://i.imgur.com/eqmzZR9.png); in other words, the action gets completed succesfully. Nonetheless, the php code in `search.php` does not fill the database (by pulling Tweets from the Twitter API) like it does when running the script in the browser. I do not understand what you mean by "checking the exit code". If I type `action "C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\wget.exe"`, cmd returns that `action` is not recognized as an internal or external command, etc...