# Windows downloading file from URL to specified location in interval

Tags: vbscript, xmlhttprequest

Is it possible to download a file in intervals from a specified URL to a specified location in an easy way?

I created VBScript:

```
Set args = WScript.Arguments
path = ""
datePath = ""
Url = ""

dim filesys
Set filesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Do
    If filesys.FileExists(path) Then 
        filesys.DeleteFile path
    End If

    dim xHttp: Set xHttp = createobject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    dim bStrm: Set bStrm = createobject("Adodb.Stream")
    xHttp.Open "GET", Url, False
    xHttp.Send 
    with bStrm
      .type = 1 '//binary
       .open
       .write xHttp.responseBody
       .savetofile path, 2 '//overwrite
    end with


    If(xHttp.Status = 200) Then
        If filesys.FileExists(datePath) Then 
            filesys.DeleteFile datePath
        End If
        Set dateFile = filesys.CreateTextFile(datePath)
        dateFile.WriteLine(FormatDateTime(Now))
        dateFile.close()
    End If
    WScript.Sleep 600000
Loop
```

But it doesn't work as it returns following prompt:

> This page is accessing information that is not under its control. This
>   poses a security risk. Do you want to continue?

I tried to disable notification by changing internet options but it also doesn't work for me.
I need the script to work even when I am absence in my job thus I need to improve/change this to be maintenance-free. It also needs to work on Windows OS.

I also tried to use powershell > wget but then authentication problem occures as file i need to get is in secured business's infranet and need to use my login credentials I tried to provide them in URL or as wget arguments --user/-password - It doesn't work because login procedure requires redirections. VBScript uses my current session thus infranet security system allows it to get in.

Is anyone able to help with my problem?

Comment: I’d use wget + windows task scheduler for something like that … https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14923562/running-a-php-script-using-wget-and-windows-scheduler

Comment: Hi, I found this question before, and part of this code exits in my script. My problem is, that this way returns prompt which stops my loop. So it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Add a task in Task Scheduler with whatever schedule you like, and in the action, add this:

start a program: Powershell

argument: `wget URL -OutFile FILEADDRESS`

Comment: Can I ask why a down vote? this answer just works!

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your reply, i will try it. When it comes to down vote It wasn't me - I gave you up vote just right now. Anyway  i have no reputation for that my vote will be visible.

Comment: Is it possible to also update file containing date when wget finishes download?

Comment: yes, use this argument instead:


`wget URL -OutFile FILEADDRESS; if($?) {echo $(Get-Date) > DATEFILEADDRESS}`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try.

Comment: Unfortunately this way doesn't work as there are security restrictions in an infranet which needs authorization. I tried to use `https://login:pass@host` in URL or `--user user --password pass` preffix but it still returns _Username/Password Authentication Failed._
Waiting for more ideas.

Comment: you should have mentioned that there is authentication. whether it is intranet proxy or basic authentication or jwt, you can still use wget. check `man wget` for detail about different authentications. If its basic or jwt, you should add a header with user/pass or token.