# PowerShell script run using Windows Task Scheduler is not running a SQL Server SSIS DTEXEC.EXE job

Tags: sql-server, windows, powershell, ssis, scheduled-tasks

Hopefully this question is unique enough not to be a duplicate.  I have a PowerShell script which does two things.

1. Inserts records into a SQL Server table
2. Writes text to a text file

For the purpose of this post, I have simplified the script.  On my computer, the script is located at C:\Temp\ssis.ps1.  Following is the contents of the script.

```
DTEXEC.EXE /F "C:\Temp\ssisjob.dtsx"    
$date = Get-Date
Write-Output "This PowerShell script file was last run on $date" >> C:\Temp\test.txt
```

When I manually run this PowerShell script, records are inserted into the SQL Server table, and a line of text is written to the test.txt file.  If I schedule this script to run using Windows Task Scheduler, a new line of text is written to the text file, but the records are not inserted into the SQL Server table. This tells me that Windows Task Scheduler is able to run the PowerShell script. However, for some unknown reason, Windows Task Scheduler seems to not want to run the SSIS job (DTEXEC.EXE) part of the script.  Event Viewer confirms there is an issue with the SSIS job.  I am running Microsoft SQL Server 2014, Developer Version.

[image]
[image]

In my task, on the Actions tab, the Add arguments field has the following reference: C:\Temp\ssis.ps1.  Task Scheduler is configured to run with the highest privileges.

[image]

I have tried all of the following Execution Policies in PowerShell.  Regardless of the Execution Policy I select, my experience does not change.

- Bypass
- Unrestricted
- RemoteSigned

The History tab in Task Scheduler has *information* events, but no *error* events.

[image]

I do not have the permission to view the SQL Server logs (this is a production server).

I have been debugging this issue for a few weeks, and I have read numerous posts here on Stack Overflow, yet I still cannot seem to find the answer, so hopefully I have done my due diligence before making a new post here.  I could add some additional observations, but I do not want my post here to get extensively long.  If anyone has any hints or tips or insight that might lead me down the right path, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First red flag is that the package is in your personal folder. Maybe the scheduler account can't get to it. Can you find any windows scheduler logs? (i.e. in the windows event log). Try moving the package somewhere easier to access like C:\temp and see if it works, but also find a log that describes the execution of your script. What version of SSIS? SQL Server has it's own scheduling and logging infrastructure

Comment: Thank you very much for these tips and ideas Nick.  I will try the idea's you have shared here.  I will respond again once I have tried these ideas.  I really appreciate the thoughts here! :)

Comment: Today I moved my PowerShell script to C:\Temp, and I experience the same issue.  I was able to find a event in the Event Viewer which confirms the SSIS job is failing.  I am running SQL Server 2014 Developer version.  I have edited my post to reflect these new findings.  Thank you for any additional thoughts you might have! :)

Comment: So what does the event say on the details tab? please copy/paste. What's the package protection level? What security are you using to connect to the database (SQL or windows authenticated). Something else to try is set the scheduled job up to run as yourself - press the "Change User or Group" button and enter your credentials.

Comment: Thank you again for the ideas here Nick! I’ve revised my post to include the details tab of the event viewer. I am not seeing information in the details tab to help pinpoint the solution here. When creating the SSIS job, the package protection level I selected was 'Encrypt sensitive data with user key'.  I also tried 'Do not save sensitive data' and 'Encrypt sensitive data with password'.  Both these display an authentication error in PowerShell.  When connecting to SQL, I am using SQL authentication. I did verify the General tab of my Scheduled Task is configured to run using my user account.

Comment: There are many things we can try but it would be better to try and capture the error message. What happens if, instead of calling the powershell script, you just call `DTEXEC.EXE /F "C:\Temp\ssisjob.dtsx"` directly? The task scheduler logs should at least say "I started the job and finished"

Comment: Oh wow, thanks for the cool recommendation Nick.  I didn't know that I could type DTEXEC.EXE /F "C:\Temp\ssisjob.dtsx" directly into Task Scheduler.  This is a great way to eliminate PowerShell from the scenario. Task Scheduler does indeed have events such as Task Started and Task Completed. I've added an image to my post. However, no changes were made to the records in the SQL database. Since Task Scheduler does not give any errors, I suspect I must turn to the SQL Server logs?  I don't have permission to the SQL Server logs in production, but I can replicate this on a VM in my lab.

Comment: As per here https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162810(v=sql.105).aspx try adding `/Cons` to the command line to get more detailed results. Maybe it connects to a different database. You could use _SQL Profiler_ to observe activity when it is functioning and not functioning, if you have sufficient access.

Comment: I see you're getting operational code **2**. According to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12964998/windows-7-task-scheduler-keeps-returning-operational-code-2 it means task scheduler can't find your file. You might need to fully qualify `DTExec` (with C:\Program files etc. in front). I'm suprised it doesn't make the error more obvious

Comment: Thank you for the continual assistance Nick!  I think you probably have pin-pointed the issue here.  I think there was some unusual things done with the path to the dtexec.exe file shortly after the install of SQL Server. I am going to open a ticket with the install team to learn what they did during install. I did try the fully qualified path in my Task Scheduler, yet still the job doesn't run.  I am almost certain now the issue was due to the unusual things done by the install team to the dtexec.exe file :)

Comment: I'm interested in whether you were able to resolve your problem, Jeremy? Did you get to the bottom of it?

Comment: Hi David. I am somewhat embarrassed to admit that I am still struggling to automate the running of an SSIS package using Windows Task Scheduler. I actually have a few weeks of available now to dedicate to this, so I can pick this investigation up again. Is there anything tips or insight or highlights that you can share that might help us solve this? I'll be retesting this in my lab over the next few days.

Comment: Hello @Nick.McDermaid. It sure has been some time, but I've finally resolved this issue. 2 adjustments solved this issue. 1. Instead of exporting to Excel, I am exporting to a Flat File. 2. Per your recommendations, instead of configuring the Task Scheduler to run a PowerShell file, I have configured Task Scheduler to run the DTEXEC.EXE file. If you want to post an answer, I will definitely accept your answer. Thanks again for the help with this one!

Comment: Thanks for coming back with your solution, today you made the internet a better place :) I"m glad you sorted it. Why don't you post your solution and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I came up with. Instead of exporting the file to Excel, I exported to a flat file (txt file). Also, using Nick McDermaids excellent recommendations, instead of using PowerShell in Task Scheduler, I started the dtexec.exe file in Task Scheduler.

**Task Sheduler Actions Tab**

- Keep the action as Start a program
- In Program/script, type dtexec.exe
- In Add arguments, type /f "C:\path\to\example.dtsx
- Leave the Start In box empty